# why adding keyword `let` or `var` makes code uncompilable

Tags: angular, typescript

In following component class, if I add `let` keyword, the code doesn't compile. Why?

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  name2:string;//let name2:string doesn't compile.

  constructor(){

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages, when compiling fails? Please add them to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` and `var` are only required/allowed for local variables, not for class fields.

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  name2:string;//let name2:string doesn't compile.

  constructor(){
    var x = 5; // ok
    let y = 5; // ok
    const z = 5; // ok
  }
}
```

In a class outside a method (or constructor) only variable initialization and method declaration is allowed, therefore `let` is redundant and therefore not allowed.

Comment: Any hint what the downvote is for? If you know better post a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are in a class :

```
export class HelloComponent
```

In a class, you declare properties/members that will be accessible like this

```
let hello = new HelloComponent();
console.log(hello.name2); // In your case, shows "undefined"
```

This an **object property**.

For `var` and `let`, you create **block-scoped variables** : those are variables that will die once you leave the block of code you're in, such as a function.

Comment: To better understand these concepts, the OP should read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html